# Mailboxer attachments via CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, mailboxer

I'm trying to send messages with attachments, using **CarrierWave**.
In **Mailboxer** gem I find that the uploader mounted [here.](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/4b2681c1790b823f7b493fb00b41e9899bb90ebe/app/models/message.rb#L13)
It uses `AttachmentUploader` for the field `:attachment`

In base functionality all works good. Attached files stored in public/uploads folder.

But I need add custom functionality to [AttachmentUploader](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/4b2681c1790b823f7b493fb00b41e9899bb90ebe/app/uploaders/attachment_uploader.rb) (Eg. change the path to store attachments etc.).

I trying create my own `attachment_uploader.rb` in `app/uploaders` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added to `initializers/mailboxer.rb`

```
...
class AttachmentUploader < AllAttachmentUploader

end
```

It allow me inherit from AllAttachmentUploader to AttachmentUploader which was defined in Mailboxer.